# Parcel + Vue multi bundle

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bundle, parcel, parceljs

I have the following project structure

```
/
-- dest/
-- public/
---- widget.html
-- src/
---- runner.ts
---- runner.scss
---- widget/
------ components/
-------- ComponentA.vue
-------- ComponentB.vue
------ App.vue
------ widget.ts
```

my goal is to:

1. bundle the Vue app under `src/widget` -> `dest/widget` using `public/widget.html as the`entry`
2. bundle `src/runner.ts` -> `dest/runner.js`
3. bundle `src/runner.scss` -> `dest/runner.css`

I will load `runner.js` on my site ( header of footer ). `runner.js` will create an iframe and load `dest/widget.html` into the iframe source, which will in turn load the app inside the iframe. `runner.js` will also load `runner.css` and inject it into the page ( dynamically, outside of the bundling flow )

problems:

1. since Parcel is forcing file hashes, i do not understand how `runner.ts` can reference the `widget.html` if the hash keeps changing
2. can i do this entire set of requirement in a single bundler / config?

I understand these are rather unusual requirement but this is what the app needs to do and this is what needs to happen, I just need help to find the solution to achieve this in the right way without hacking or doing crazy stuff :)

Comment: Hashes should be applied to `js` and `css`, `html` file should be left alone

Comment: I'm not sure if what you are trying to do is simply have two files `runner.js` and `runner.css` without the file name hashes -- but if this is what you want, try *not* using the widget.html page as an entrypoint. Rather skip the use of the html file and use the *javascript* file as the entrypoint. In this way you will get just those two files and no hash in the filename. I don't need an index.html in my setup, I'm using Ruby/Rails and just want to get the js bundle without hashes in the filename so this is what I do. Try a command similar to:  `parcel src/runner.js`